# If a user's answer is not in intents in Dialogflow, why does the answer change from person to person?

Tags: dialogflow-cx

If a user's answer is not in intents in Dialogflow,
why does the answer change from person to person?
Is it because of the AI learning function? Or is it set randomly?

I want to know the algorithm for why it varies from person to person.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create a agent, the 'Start page' preconfigured with [Event Handlers](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event), including events such as ["sys.no-match-default" and "sys.no-input-default"](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/handler#event-built-in). These handlers contain a series of random responses. [image: Agent says - sys.no-match-default]